# Rewrite boundary conditions of PDE to prepare numerical magic

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

I am trying to learn solving PINN (Physic-Informed Neural Network) problems but I do lack some analytical power.

Please consider the PDE(Burger Equation): $$u_x+u_t=\alpha u_{xx}$$
$$u(u,t=0)=-\sin(\pi x), u(x=-1,t)=u(x=1,t)=0$$
according to this link:
https://github.com/sciann/sciann-applications/blob/master/SciANN-BurgersEquation/SciANN-BurgersEquation.ipynb the boundary conditions can be wirtten as
[image]

Apppearantly I do not have the mathematical imagination we know why. Can someone please explain to me why those three equations are alike? thanks!

Also, how if sould conditions look if needed $u(-1,t)=u(1,t)$. Hence we didnot know the values but only that they are equat at the boundary.

Comment: You've certainly made an effort. Best of luck, I'll follow your future progress with great interest!